# Android layout 50% 50% fill with image over it

Tags: android, layout

I'm trying to get android layout with one half of screen in one solid color, and another half - with another solid color and over it in the center of screen will be an image. 
Is it possible to do so?

I've tried to use one layout and set gradient to it:

```
 <gradient
        android:type="linear"
        android:centerX="51%"
        android:startColor="#FF59901d"
        android:centerColor="#FF59901d"
        android:endColor="#FF2b241f"
        android:angle="270"/>
```

but it didn't work as I expected - it gave smooth color mix, not 2 colors separated each from another. I think here is needed another gradient control point.

Another option was use 2 linear layouts and fill them with different colors, it gave normal background as I want, but in this case how to position image over both layouts at the center of screen?

Comment: Use a `FrameLayout` to place your image over the colored `LinearLayout`s -- you can even just use two `View`s if all you want is color.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on @323go comment, Inside a framelayout use two linearlayout. Give weight = 1 to both. and height = 0dp (asssuming you wish to split in upper and bottom halves).

Then use a Relativelayout which fills whole screen, but has transparent background. Inside it place an imageview with center Parent Vertical as true

Answer (score 0):

Create a `RelativeLayout` with your `ImageView` aligned `centerInParent` and set the `RelativeLayout` with the following background-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:type="linear">


    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:startColor="#FF59901d"
        android:centerColor="@android:color/white"
        android:endColor="#FF2b241f"
        />
</shape>
```

Hope this helps !!